# Accessing incoming text messages on iOS 8+

Tags: ios, sms

I understand that there is no way to access SMS from SDK. Does that mean that QuickType is the only tool that has access to incoming messages (for its predictions)?  Does anyone know if it's possible to get the last incoming message like QuickType does?

Would any keyboard app be able to access text messages, from notification center maybe?

Comment: No, there is no way you can access the content of text messages as an app or keyboard extension.

Comment: What is QuickType?

Comment: A quick search will tell you that QuickType is the name Apple gave to their new iOS keyboard. Since it's not a third-party app, it can do these things you describe. Third party apps cannot do this.